# To appand url using hash without redirect to a new page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using a table with multiple rows. I want to only change the url when we click on any row. e.g if i click on first row url append to www.abc.com#1 annd for row 2 www.abc.com#2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
... onclick="location.hash='1'; return false;"
```

In the tag you want to enable this behavior for.

Comment: Great Tip. Works for me now. Hope this will work fine for my application...:)

Answer (score 0):

put `onclick` event in `<tr>` like this

```
<tr id="row6" onclick="goTo();">
      .....
   </tr>
```

then your java script

```
function goTo() {
        var input = "give your url like #1",
            frame = get("frame");

            input = "http://www.abc.com" + input;
            frame.src = input;

    }
```